# CustomBinding for this BasicHttpBinding?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, security, binding, web-config

I am having hard time converting a BasicHttpBinding to custom binding. Specifically I need to convert the security element-

```
<basicHttpBinding>
 <binding name="MySecureBasicHttpBinding">
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
   <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
   <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
 </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Can anyone help write the same in custom binding? 
Please also refer to post\doc, from where I can find out the correspondence between the security mode & values as in basicHttpBinding and those in custom bindings.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="UsernamePasswordOverHttps">
    <security
      authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"      
      messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
    <httpsTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Comment: I don't think it'll be consumable in Silverlight app if I used WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005....

Comment: You didn't mention anything about Silverlight in your question! Anyway message security version should not make any problems. It just says which specifications should be used if requested by other components. BasicHttpBinding use this message security version as well.